# How to load special characters (non-English letters) in SQL Loader

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

Some of my developer_id are in foreign language (special character). I googled how to handle those characters, and what people said was using

```
NVARCHAR2()
```

or use:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (N'你好');
```

However, I used NVARCHAR2() in stage and on all the tables but still doesn't work for me (the original datatype for developer_id was VARCHAR2()). Also, the insert statement with N at the beginning is not working for SQL Loader I think.

What should I do?

Here is where the problem shows:
[image]

Here is my ctl. file
[image]

Here is the datatype for all the data in the flat file:
[image]

The character set for the flat file is UTF-8. I thought I have successfully solved this problem by changing my Encoding when pre-loading the data to stage table, but the same problem still shows up when I finished importing my data to stage.
[image]

Comment: What character set is the file encoded in?  What is the database character set?  What is the database's national character set?

Comment: Seems you need to add `CHARACTERSET .....` just after `LOAD DATA` within the .ctl file.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I've updated the problem by adding more information to my question.